# secp256k1: is it theoretically possible to generate same signature with different key, message hash and k?

Tags: elliptic-curves, signature, secp256k1

For a given private key $d$, random $k$ and message hash $h$ is it possible that there exists a different set of $d$, $k$ and $h$ which produces the same signature using $\text{secp256k1}$ curve?

Comment: Which signature are we talking? Probably ECDSA since you are using Secp256k1. The answer yes, the finding is hard. Simple argument, the signature space is not belong to nobody.

Comment: @kelalaka Yeah, I am talking about `ECDSA`. It would nice if you could give more detailed explanation of why is it possible

Comment: There's an infinite message space and a finite signature space.  Thus there must be an infinite number of instances where the same signature is used.  As kelalaka noted, finding them is hard because the signature space, will finite, is vast.

Comment: @Swashbuckler, I refer to message hash as its space is also finite. Edited, thx!

Comment: Now the question is how many bits have k and h combined, and how many has the created signature? If k+h > sig then collisions are unavoidable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We want $(r,s)$ same for two different set of $d,k,h$

In ECDSA

- $r = x_0([k]G) \bmod n$ where $k \in [1,n-1]$ and $x_o$ is the x-coordinate of the scalar multiplication $[k]G$
- $s = k^{-1}\cdot (h+r\cdot d)$ where $h$ is the left  most bits of $h$ to fit in the group order ( for simplicity we called it $h$ again).

Now we want same $(r,s)$ for $d,k,h$ and $d',k',h'$

- $r = x_0([k]G) = x_0([k']G)$ although this may indicate that $k=k'$ it is not. The reason is that the coordinate field $p$ is smaller than the order $n$ of the base point. Therefore we can have solutions other than the trivial.
- $s = k^{-1}\cdot (h+r\cdot d) = k'^{-1}\cdot (h'+r\cdot d')$,

  then with $k'=k$ we have;

  \begin{align}
     (d'-d)\cdot r &= (h-h') \\
    \end{align}

  then with $k'\neq k$ with $c = k^{-1}$ and $c' = k'^{-1}$ ( for our eyes) we have;

  \begin{align}
     c'\cdot h + c' \cdot r \cdot d &= c\cdot h' + c \cdot r \cdot d' \\
     c'\cdot h -c\cdot h'  &=  c \cdot c \cdot d' -c' \cdot r \cdot d \\
     c'\cdot h -c\cdot h'  &=  r \cdot ( c \cdot d' -c' \cdot d) \\
    \end{align}

As we can see by knowing $r$;

Either

- we need to find a proper $d'$ for a given $d$ for given different hash values. This is free since we found the private key by just arithmetics.
- OR, we need to find a message that produces desired hash value $h'$ so that we have equality. This is hard since we need to break pre-image resistance of SHA256.

As we can see it is possible but hard.

For the case $k'\neq k$ the calculations are similar.

Comment: For easy to understand I've only look the case $k=k'$. Arguments are similar.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! The side question was if signature can be used to check `message` equality and as I can see, omitting hash collision, that there are exists different `d`, `h` and `k` which belongs to the same field and can produce matching signature

Comment: @Yaroslav why do you need a signature to test the quality of the messages? In theory, signature security is not about the security of the messages. It is about forging a signature. As you see that is a hard problem. You need to compare securely see [Socialist millionaire problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialist_millionaire_problem)

Comment: The wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm calculates `s` as `=−1⋅(ℎ+⋅)` which is different from equation in your answer =−1⋅ℎ+⋅. Are they equal?

Comment: thanks! Could you give a bit more details about why is discrete logarithm solver is needed to find `d` prime from `(′−)⋅=(ℎ−ℎ′)`? Or is it needed because `s` is modulus `p`?

Comment: Ok, corrected that one, too, since $d$ is already a private key, just publish your public key.

Comment: ok, so based on the last equation finding `d` prime and `h` prime should be pretty trivial if we know `d`, `h` and `r` of the original signature. And the only requirement for `k` is to have the same `x` coordinate as the original `k`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Sorry for my mistakes. If we know $r$ then we can throw $d'$ and then $h'$ is there.

Comment: By throwing you mean picking arbitrary `d'`? So then picking arbitrary `h'` should be enough to get `d'`, right? Also, if `h == h'`(equal message `h - h = 0`) does that state that for any random `k` there is one and only d to get the same signature?

Comment: Yes. yes, either $h'$ or $d'$ one must pick this is where the freedom occurs. For $h=h'$ case remember I've taken $k = k'$, Wrote the other equation, too. I wonder what is the usage of this question.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot! It came from a question "If signature can be a proof of message equality" For example can we say that two objects are equal if their signatures match, instead of doing full field to field compression. Then I just could not find anything related to ECDSA signature collision in the internet.

Comment: Remember the signature include the message or at least the encrypted message.

Comment: I think `k` and `k'` should be power `-1` in your equations for `′≠` case

Comment: @Yaroslav yes, thanks, and that will make the equation more unreadable, let introduce some new variables.

Answer (score 4):

> For a given private key $d$, random $k$ and message hash $h$: is it possible that there exists a different set of $d$, $k$ and $h$ which produces the same [ECDSA](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#page=49) signature using the [$\text{secp256k1}$](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#page=13) curve?

**Yes**, and further it's easy to explicitly compute an alternate $(d',k',h')$ that matches all reasonable meanings of *"different set of $d$, $k$ and $h$"*:

- different [tuples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple): $(d',k',h')\ne(d,k,h)$
- [pairwise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_comparison) different values: $d'\ne d$, $k'\ne k$, and $h'\ne h$ (which implies the above)
- different [sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)): $\{d',k',h'\}\ne\{d,k,h\}$, which is literally what's asked, but rather exotic: order of elements does not matter in sets, thus $\{1,2,3\}=\{2,3,1\}$, and  $\{1,1,2\}=\{2,2,1\}$. Also, that set equality has two different possible meanings depending on if we assimilate hashes (like $h$) to integers (like $k$ and $d$) for the purpose of comparison, which is a matter of convention.

---

"Same signature" means $(r,s)$ is unchanged, that is $r$ and $s$ both are unchanged.

In ECDSA, $r$ is unchanged if and only if $k'=k$ or $k'=n-k$. I settle for $k'=n-k$, which implies $k'\ne k$ because $n$ is odd.

Given the above, $s$ is unchanged if and only $k'^{-1}\,(h'+r\,d')\equiv k^{-1}\,(h+r\,d)\pmod n$. That is $h+h'+r\,(d+d')\equiv0\pmod n$, thus $d'=-d-r^{-1}\,(h+h')\bmod n$.

Thus we only need to

- compute $r$ the normal way (if it's not a given),
- select a different $h'$ (overwhelmingly likely, it's enough to hash a different message; otherwise, we retry with another message),
- compute $k'\gets n-k$ and $d'\gets-d-r^{-1}\,(h+h')\bmod n$.

That insures $(d',k',h')$ yields the same signature $(r,s)$ as $(d,k,h)$ does, with $k'\ne k$ and $h'\ne h$, and overwhelmingly likely $d'\ne d$ (otherwise, we retry with another message/$h'$).

If we do not assimilate bitsrings and integers, $h'\ne h\implies\{d',k',h'\}\ne\{d,k,h\}$. If we do, it's overwhelmingly likely that $h'$ is neither $d'$ nor $k'$ (otherwise, we retry with another message/$h'$).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Isn't `s` equals to =−1⋅(ℎ+⋅)? According to wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm

Comment: Based on @kelalaka answer (′−)⋅=(ℎ−ℎ′) states that for equal `h` and `h` prime for any random `k` and `r` respectively there is only one `d` that can produce the same signature for given `h` and `k`, is that right?

Comment: @Yaoslav: Oups, fixed the missing parenthesis and a sign error. My answer differs from kelalaka's because I took $k'=n-k$, because it's unclear what you mean by "different ___set___ of $d$, $k$ and $h$", and thus I decided to change as much components of $(d,k,h)$ as possible.

Answer (score 3):

It is totally possible and fairly easy to see without any advanced maths.
The curve has order n (n Points in the curve) the private key d is [0... n-1] and the random number k [1... n-1] and there are 2^256 possible values for h.
So there are n*(n-1)*2^256 possible inputs (d, k, h combinations).
The output is r, s. Where r is there x part of a point so there are definitely not more (actually less) values than there are points on the curve and s is taken mod n, so there are not more than n possible values for that either.

So in total there are around n*n*2^256 inputs for maximal than n*n signatures.
So the pigeonhole principle tells us that there must be multiple inputs that produce the same output.

Comment: That's a proof of existence for the _different tuples_ reading of the question. It does not work for the _pairwise different_ reading, and I scratch my head at if it can be made to work for the _different set_ wording.

Comment: @fgrieu I am not sure if I understand correctly what you mean, but it also works when all d', k' and h' are different from d, k and h. This just reduces each factor by 1. So it does not really reduce the total number of possible inputs that much.

Comment: I mean: take $(r,s)=f(d,k,h)$ with $r$ some unspecified function of $(d,k,h)$ and $s=k$. Then there exists no $d',k',h'$ with $f(d',k',h')=f(d,k,h)$ and pairwise different values: $d'\ne d$, $k'\ne k$, and $h'\ne h$. The pigeonhole principle is not enough for a _pairwise different_ reading of the question. It's more difficult to exhibit a counterexample for the pigeonhole principle in the literal reading of the question: _"different [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics))"_, but I think that's possible.

Comment: Ah, ok, yes your right