# Is it possible to recover the private key if the same message is signed twice with different nonce?

Tags: elliptic-curves, signature

Sorry if this question is misguided, I'm a software developer and not a cryptographer.

Let's say I have a public key, and 2 signed messages.

Signed message 1:

```
message_hash_1
signature_1.r
signature_1.s
```

Signed message 2:

```
message_hash_2
signature_2.r
signature_2.s
```

Assumptions:

```
message_hash_1 == message_hash_2
signature_1.r != signature_2.r
signature_1.s != signature_2.s
```

I've read in https://www.bertcmiller.com/2021/12/28/glimpse_nonce_reuse.html that it is possible to recover the private key if `r` is the same across the signed messages, but `s` is different.

Is it possible to recover the private key if the `message_hash` is the same, but `signature_1.r`/`signature_2.r` and `signature_1.s`/`signature_2.r` are both different? So the nonce with which the message was signed was different, but the message and private key were the same across both signatures.

I'm using NIST P-256 elliptic curve.

Comment: For ECDSA we have a dupe for this. could you search for it? in one minute..

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: Welcome. You might be interested in these, too. 1) [secp256k1: is it theoretically possible to generate same signature with different key, message hash and k?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/89809/18298) 2) [How does the "biased-k attack" on (EC)DSA work?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/44644/18298)

Comment: Here a +1 for you as a fast accept and don't forget to upvote the helpful answers on your cause.